# Do some stuff before saving form with CreateView

Tags: python, django

I want to populate GenericIPAddress Field before saving an instance in CreateView. It has to be done in View not in Form Class, because of access to request variable. Can I do that? Which method I had to override and how? Code I'm working with:

**models.py**

```
class Message(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    email = models.EmailField()
    message = models.TextField(max_length=1200)
    ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField(null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author + '/' + self.message[:20]
```

**forms.py**

```
class MessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ['author', 'email', 'message']
        labels = {
            'author': 'Autor',
            'email': 'E-mail',
            'message': 'Wiadomość'
        }
```

**views.py**

```
class SendMessage(CreateView):
    form_class = MessageForm
    template_name = 'blog/send_message.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        result = super(SendMessage, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        ip, is_routable = get_client_ip(request)
        if ip:
            self.fields['ip_address'] = ip  #I do it wrong
        return result
```

Comment: override `form_valid` function of CBV

Comment: Are u sure it has request param? I wrote function based view already, It does the job.

Comment: check my answer please, i just copy your code with reference to form_valid() to give you an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def form_valid(self,form):
        super(SendMessage, self).form_valid(form)
        ip, is_routable = get_client_ip(self.request)
        if ip:
            self.fields['ip_address'] = ip       
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

I am using your code as a reference to tell you how you can access `request` in form_valid.
for more usage refer to this article [here](https://www.webforefront.com/django/modelclassbasedviews.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from app.models import Message


@receiver(pre_save, sender=Message)
def some_signal(sender, **kwargs):
    # populate GenericIPAddress Field
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/

Comment: Can you tell me how can I set `ip_address` fileld to that form request in this function?